# Expected number of points

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, gambling

Using the work made by the authors of the paper below, I have used the same type of recursive formulas for badminton.

Not really sure how I can share my work, but at least I want to share my findings:

I get an expected 37.17 pts for every set in a 50-50 game. And I expect a 2.5 number of sets to be played. Is it correct to assume that the expected number of points in for the match are 37.17 * 2.5 = 92.9 ?

Is this number also the median (92.9) ?

If the information I have provided is not sufficient to get the answers to the question above, can you pls let me know what else I need to provide ?

thanks

[Inspiration work](http://strategicgames.com.au/excel.pdf)

Comment: I did not read the linked paper carefully, and I have no idea how closely badminton parallels tennis. Just from what you say, I think your mean number of points in a match is correct. If the distribution of points is nearly symmetrical, the mean and median should be nearly equal. However, if the distribution of points is (say) strongly right-skewed, then the median might be substantially smaller than the mean. (The mean would be "pulled to the right" by the long right tail.)

Comment: @BruceET Maybe the info I gave was not totally clear. The distribution is righ-skewed. If it was symmetrical, the mean = median would be 37.13 * 3 = 111.51. Because it is skewed i have the 92.9. thank you